# Prove $\tan A_1<\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sin A_1}{\sum_{i=1}^n \cos A_1}<\tan A_n$ for $0<A_1<A_2<\dots<A_n<\pi/2$.

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

> If $0<A_1<A_2<\dots<A_n<\pi/2$, then prove that
>   $$\tan A_1<\frac{\sin A_1+\sin A_2+\dots+\sin A_n}{\cos A_1+\cos A_2+\dots+\cos A_n}<\tan A_n$$

I have approached it in this way that $\sin\theta$ increases from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $\cos\theta$ decreases from $0$ to $\pi/2$. I could not proceed after that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$0<A_1<A_2<\dots<A_n<\pi/2$$
$$0<\sin A_1<\sin A_2<\dots<\sin A_n<1$$
$$1>\cos A_1>\cos A_2>\dots>\cos A_n>0$$
$$\frac{\sin A_1+\sin A_2+\dots+\sin A_n}{\cos A_1+\cos A_2+\dots+\cos A_n}>\frac{\sin A_1+\sin A_1+\dots+\sin A_1}{\cos A_1+\cos A_2+\dots+\cos A_n}>\frac{\sin A_1+\sin A_1+\dots+\sin A_1}{\cos A_1+\cos A_1+\dots+\cos A_1}=\frac{n\sin A_1}{n\cos A_1}=\tan A_1$$
The other inequality involving $\tan A_n$ is similar.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't need any more trigonometry than the remark you've already made - what's actually going on is that if $x_1<x_2<...<x_n$ and $y_1>y_2>...>y_n$ are positive reals,
$$\frac{x_1}{y_1}<\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{y_1+y_2+...+y_n}<\frac{x_n}{y_n}$$
Try to prove this inequality (hint: a lower bound for the top of the fraction is $nx_1$).

Comment: couldn t get the hint.):